# Appcelerator studio installing is not working

Tags: configuration, appcelerator-studio

My OS is `windows 10` (64 bit OS), I got `Appcelerator Studio.exe` for 32 bit.

I installed successfully on my system. When I try to launch the studio I am getting error as below

[image]

When I browse for this issue I got info about adding below lines into `AppceleratorStudio.ini` and I did that too

```
-vw
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\javaw.exe
```

But still I am having the same issue. When I look at the screenshot below, I hope it `Appcelerator Studio` tried to read javaw.exe from `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appcelerator Studio(32bit) will work on 32 bit and 64 bit OS environments. But, you need to have 32bit Java 1.7 installed in the system.

In your case, it should be `-vm` rather than `-vw`

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\javaw.exe
```

Assuming, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\javaw.exe is a 32bit

You can find 32bit Java in `Program Files (x86)` folder in windows 64 bit machines.

If it's not installed, you can download and install directly from here: http://go.appcelerator.com/installer_jdk_windows_1_7_80

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\javaw.exe  is 64 bit

Comment: Studio requires 32 bit Java 1.7, can you change and try out. You should find that in `Program files (x86)`.